# Append to a list in loop using tf.range

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a simple tf.function where I iterate a certain number of times, each time appending to a list or modifying it at an index. Recently I tried to switch from Range to tf.range(), and I get a few errors. Two MREs that produce the error:

```
@tf.function
def my_function():
    outputs = [None for _ in range(10)]
    for i in tf.range(10):
        outputs[i] = tf.expand_dims(tf.zeros([10, 10000]), axis=1)
    return outputs
```

produces
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor` and

```
@tf.function
def my_function():
    outputs = []
    for _ in tf.range(10):
        outputs.append(tf.expand_dims(tf.zeros([10, 10000]), axis=1))
    return outputs
```

produces `The tensor <tf.Tensor 'while/ExpandDims:0' shape=(10, 1, 10000) dtype=float32> cannot be accessed from FuncGraph(name=my_function, id=xxxx), because it was defined in FuncGraph(name=while_body_17, id=xxxx), which is out of scope.`

How do I keep the same functionality with the list while avoiding these errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used TensorFlow tensor instead of a Python list

```py
@tf.function
def my_function():
    outputs = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=10, dynamic_size=False)
    for i in tf.range(10):
        output = tf.expand_dims(tf.zeros([10, 10000]), axis=1)
        outputs = outputs.write(i, output)
    return outputs.stack()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know of an alternative of the .stack() method that allows an axis argument? The actual shape of my data is (None, 1, 10000), and I would like it to be stacked to (None, 10, 10000) instead of (10, None, 1, 10000). Thanks!

Comment: The solution to my previous comment is ```tf.concat([outputs.read(i) for i in range(self.input_len)], axis=1)```